# need assistance with sql injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

First, I'm not trying to hack or do anything illegal. Thought I let you guys know. I have a client that want's me to do some modifications on his system, when I was looking at it I notice that NOTHING was escaped. I'm not joking, nothing is being escaped. I explained to him that it's insecure to have a system like that. He then proceeds to tell me that he's had his system like this for few years and nothing has happened. I need to show him that his system is not safe, but I really don't know to do perform an sql injection. Here's a few queries that use $_GET and are not escaped.

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(joined,'%M %d, %Y') as \"Joined\" FROM `members` WHERE `name` LIKE '".$ltr."%' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT $page,50
```

Here's another one:

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id=$thisladder[grid]
```

The only thing that I see that "might" clean the $_GET is this function:

```
if (!ini_get('register_globals')) {
   $superglobals = array($_SERVER, $_ENV,
       $_FILES, $_COOKIE, $_POST, $_GET);
   if (isset($_SESSION)) {
       array_unshift($superglobals, $_SESSION);
   }
   foreach ($superglobals as $superglobal) {
       extract($superglobal, EXTR_SKIP);
   }
}
```

It's possible that the function above may be sanitizing the variables. And yes, the system also uses register globals, which is also bad.

I also made a backup, just in case.

Comment: Do you want to know how to prevent an SQL injection, or prove to your client that it's insecure?

Comment: Oh man, not only they don't escape anything, but they *explicitly* emulate the `register_globals` functionality if it's disabled! This is a first!

Comment: I don't know how to prove it. But I do know that mysql_real_escape and prepared statements are the way to go.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this without a full variable trace. Where do the values of **$ltr** and **$thisladder** come from?

Comment: "... he's had his system like this for few years and nothing has happened." By that same logic, he should conclude, "I've never been in a car accident before, so I don't need to wear a seat belt."

Comment: A quick google will return lots of `SQL Injection by Example` sites.

Comment: $ltr and $thisladder come from $_GETs. So a url sql injection would be used on these. 

Columns for table members are: id(primary), name, password, email
Columns for table group are:id(primary),name,logo,ann,active,priority,created,platform

The table members has a lot more columns , IMs, settings, etc.

Comment: I tried `domain.com/standings.php?lid=\''; DROP TABLE members; --`
no luck

Comment: Only because your social skills are not good enough to just tell the person you're working for what needs to be fixed, you need to solve that problem technically? You should better fix your problem at it's root. And not tell somebody else you're familiar with SQL injections when you're not.

Comment: can you show us the code used to log in to the system? or are there any other SQL queries that are publicly available and use may POST data?

Comment: Are you sure you want to drop a table from your client's system as an example?!?

Comment: Yes? I already have the backup dump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't say it better than http://xkcd.com/327/.

[image]

But then again, as [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746357/need-assistance-with-sql-injection/7746450#7746450) says, forget SQL injection, [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is much, much worse. Never thought I'd actually see it *emulated*, just in case it's off.

Comment: god we're such nerds, couldn't stop laughing at those images lol. So globals are worst than injections? o_0

Comment: @user962449, with `register_globals`, you can just replace the value of pretty much any variable by simply including it in your GET request, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Some fun things to show your 'friend' how stupid his code is:

```
http://example.com/badscript.php?_GET[]=ha+ha+I+pwned+your+GET+superglobal
http://example.com/badscript.php?_SESSION[issuperuser]=1
```

This sort of thing is **EXACTLY** why register_globals is such an outright F'ingly moronic idea, and (after FAR too long) has finally been made to default to OFF.

Forgot SQL injection - that idiotic piece of code is allowing remote PHP variable injection.

Comment: @Marc B: I beg to differ, that code won't work whether or not register globals is on. `$_SESSION` might get overwritten if it is off and the session not yet initialized, but `session_start` would have deleted it anyway. You might want to reference a PHP version until that was possible when register globals was set to on.

Comment: @hakre: true enough, the session one depends entirely on when session_start is called relative to the pseudo-register globals. Just using this to demonstrate just how BAD register_globals can potentially be.

Comment: @MarcB: The pseudo-register globals actually uses `EXTR_SKIP`. So if session was started, it won't work. If session is started later on, the `$_SESSION` array would be reset anyway. But with register_globals there once was a time when this stuff actually was possible ^^ ;)

Answer (score 1):

if login code looked something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=\''.$_POST['username'].'\' AND password=\''.$_POST[password].'\'';
$result = mysql_query($query);
etc, etc...
```

try typing this into the login fields

```
username = "whatever"
password = "' OR 1"
```

make sense?

Comment: Passwords are hashed. So I guess the script is not that bad :/

Comment: then use "' OR 1" for the username instead.

Comment: Note, that I'm not wiz with sql injections. SO I just type `' OR 1` ?

Comment: @user962449, you could just use something like "admin'--" for username. That would make the query something like `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='admin' -- ' AND ...`. Anything following `--` is a comment.

Comment: @Radu good call. this way you can log in as your boss if you know his username.

Comment: @user962449 it's easy, just think of how what you input will affect the query. if it allows you to enter quote marks, you can do whatever you want. try for username `{bosses username here}' --` as stated by @Radu

Comment: Looks like that's the only thing that's being sanitize! I couldn't find the escape function in the system (pretty big), but I did find it online:http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Anti-SQL-Injection-Function_18.htm

same function name and same attributes. Did people stop believing in the mysql_real_escape function?

Comment: @user962449 there are functions that wil go through your request data automatically and escape each variable appropriately. this could be the case for your app.